# how to store a hive table in .xlsx format?

Tags: hive, hdfs

I create a hive table with below query

```
create table t1 row format delimited fields terminated by '|' stored as textfile;

load data inpath 'l1.csv' overwrite into table t1;
```

But,I want to store my table t1 in .xlsx format? not textfile.

Comment: What is your motivation? What is the next step?

Comment: i want that output table in an excel format.

Comment: Excel can also open text or CSV files if it is done right. I do not see the benefit of storing data as .xlsx.

Comment: I want to upload a excel sheet on google drive.that’s why I need an excel format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am from python background , if you want to store any hive data into
>   excel format  , you may use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) in python. It provides a way
>   to write any output to excel.

**Before that , you need to connect to hive using any modules like pyhs2 etc and capture data in any variables and then can write to excel.**